# Using filter_input() as a class variable in php

Tags: php, superglobals, filter-input

I have the following:

```
class FOO{  
public $HTTP_HOST = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

I don't know why it shouldn't work, but I imagine if it is producing errors there is a good reason. Should I do this another way? Is calling superglobals into a class variable a bad idea? I just wanted to cash it to save myself from typing a lot, but if I need to access it directly each time I don't mind.

Comment: When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: What superglobal are you using? Did you mean `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: You can't call a function in a property initial value. Do it in the class constructor.